# How to remove Left Column callout programmatically in magento?

Tags: magento

How to remove Left Column callout programmatically in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why only programmatically?

You can change on your design configuration to set 1 column template...
Or if you want to remove an template customization left column, you will need discover what block it's calling and comment/remove:

```
echo $this->getChild('name_block');
```

To discover block is calling, you need to enable template hints, look what template.phtml is showing and search for tempalte.phtml name on your template layout folder...

Comment: I want to replace left column callout with another block, only when it is enabled from backend. is it possible???

Comment: Do you want to show this another column by a condition? like:


    if (condition) {
        echo $this->getChildHtml('myTemplateHtml');
    } else {
        echo $this->getChildHtml('defaultTemplateHtml');
    }


Enable template hints on: http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel

With template hints what you want to change can be more easily. Try it.